# Combinatorial proof that $\frac{({10!})!}{{10!}^{9!}}$ is an integer

Tags: discrete-mathematics, factorial, combinatorial-proofs

I need help to prove that the quantity of this division :

$\dfrac{({10!})!}{{10!}^{9!}}$

is an integer number, using combinatorial proof

Comment: Hint:
Start by Proving that the numerator is $\ge$ the denominator

Comment: Wow, I've never seen combinatorial proof used this way! Can't solve it and am eager for the answer. (Changed the title since I thought it might get more attention).

Comment: Thinking out loud...what experiment could result in a count equal to the denominator?

Comment: It's easier to prove the more general rule that $$\frac{(mn)!}{m!^n}$$ is an integer. Then set $m=10, n=9!$. (It's only easier to prove the more general because it is easier to parse the factorials. Above, there are two different instances $10!$, but one is really $m!$ and the other is $mn - the fact that these values are the same is an accident but irrelevant.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have $10!$ students. You want to divide them into groups of $10$ and line of the groups; in how many different ways can you do this?

You can line up the students in $(10!)!$ different orders. Now imagine that you count them off by tens and mark a line on the ground between groups of $10$; you have $\frac{10!}{10}=9!$ groups of $10$. Since all you care about is the order of the *groups*, you can allow the students in each group of $10$ to rearrange themselves within the group as they please, and you’ll still have the same lineup of groups. Each group can rearrange itself in $10!$ different orders, and there are $9!$ groups, so there are $10!^{9!}$ different lineups of *students* that produce the same lineup of *groups*. The number of lineups of groups is therefore $\frac{(10!)!}{10!^{9!}}$, which of course must be an integer.

You can replace $10$ by $n$ and $9$ by $n-1$ and repeat the argument to show that $\dfrac{(n!)!}{n!^{(n-1)!}}$ is an integer.

Comment: Regarding your first sentence: Oh my god, when did I acquire so many students?!

Comment: @Akiva: $<$administrator$>$What, you can’t handle a mere $3,628,800$ students?$<$/administrator$>$ `:-)`

Comment: Great example Brian, helped me a lot. Thanks :)

Comment: @ihavename: You're welcome; glad it helped.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple *non*-combinatorial proof.  Still eager to see a truly combinatorial one.  The denominator contains only powers of $2$, $3$, $5$, and $7$:
$$
(10!)^{9!}=(10\cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2)^{9!}=\left(7\cdot 5^2 \cdot 3^4 \cdot 2^7\right)^{9!}=7^{9!}5^{2\cdot 9!}3^{4\cdot 9!}2^{8\cdot 9!}.
$$
The numerator, on the other hand, can be written as a product of $10!$ factors, of which $1/7$ are divisible by $7$, $1/5$ are divisible by $5$ (and $1/25$ by $25$), $1/3$ are divisible by $3$ (and $1/9$ by $9$), and $1/2$ are divisible by $2$ (and $1/4$ by $4$, and $1/8$ by $8$).   So the numerator is divisible by at least $$10!/7 = (10/7) \cdot 9! > 9!$$ factors of $7$, at least $$10!/5 + 10!/25 = (10/5 + 10/25)\cdot 9! > 2\cdot 9!$$ factors of $5$, at least $$10!/3 + 10!/9 = (10/3 + 10/9)\cdot 9! > 4\cdot 9!$$ factors of $3$, and at least $$10!/2 + 10!/4 + 10!/8 = (10/2 + 10/4 + 10/8)\cdot 9! > 8\cdot 9!$$ factors of $2$.  Hence the ratio is an integer.

---

Per the higher-ranked answer, note that generally ${a!}/{(b!)^{a/b}}$, where $b$ divides $a$, is the number of ways to partition $a$ items into groups of size $b$:
$$
N_{a,b}={{a}\choose{b}}\cdot{{a-b}\choose{b}}\cdots{{2b}\choose{b}}\cdot{{b}\choose{b}}=\frac{a!}{(a-b)!b!}\frac{(a-b)!}{(a-2b)!b!}\cdots\frac{(2b!)}{b!}\frac{b!}{b!}=\frac{a!}{(b!)^{a/b}}.
$$
This is clearly an integer; and here $a=10!$ and $b=10$.