# Prove that $(n!)!$ divisible by $(n!)^{(n-1)!}$

Tags: combinatorics, arithmetic

I was trying to think of a situation and use combinatorics to solve the problem. Any other arithmetic solution is also appreciated.

Comment: Answered here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1601400/combinatorial-proof-that-frac10109-is-an-integer

Comment: The concept is the same but this question has a more general form. I don't think it should be flagged as duplicate. Even then if you still want me to remove it I will.

Comment: Read the answer that is given in the link provided @PaoloFranchi, including the last lines of that solution. It exactly answers your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rewrite $P=\frac{(n!)!}{(n!)^{(n-1)!}}$ as $\frac{(n!)!}{(n!)(n!) \cdots (n!)}$

Number of $n!$s in the denominator is $(n-1)!$

Now, $(n-1)! \times n = n!$.
$P$ is the number of ways of arranging $n!$ things in which $n$ things  are of type 1, other $n$ things  are of type 2 and so on. Hence P is an integer.

Using a different combinatorial interpretation we can even say that,

$$\frac{(n!)!}{(n!)^{(n-1)!}(a_1)!(a_2)!....\cdots (a_r)!}$$ is also an integer where $a_i$ are non-negative integers and $a_1+a_2+a_3 \cdots + a_r=(n-1)!$.
Try to figure out how you will prove this.

Comment: Not able to prove the last one..help

Comment: @ritz301 , to prove the last one count the following:The number of ways to put n! objects in (n-1)! boxes such that each box has exatly n objects and out of the (n-1)! boxes, $a_i$ of them are of type $i$.

Comment: Awesome..thnx man!